# SSH service stops and comes back

Tags: ssh

I have a logical switch (a stack of DELL switches N1548s). For the last 2-3 days, the ssh service on the switch stops for 1 minute and then comes back. It happens 2 or 3 times a day. Has anyone seen this behaviour before??

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked for firmware updates? https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/networking-n1500-series/drivers And the logs?

Comment: Excessive bad passwords locking out the service?